# MySql query in laravel 5.4 with inner join and count

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

My sql query shows correct in phpmyadmin but when I use it in laravel 5.4 project it shows error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'project_management.addprojects.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT DISTINCT addprojects.id,addprojects.emp_id,sum(tasks.task_weight),tasks.flag from addprojects JOIN tasks ON tasks.proj_id = addprojects.id GROUP BY tasks.proj_id )

```
DB::select(" SELECT DISTINCT addprojects.proj_name,addprojects.id,
   addprojects.emp_id,sum(tasks.task_weight),tasks.flag from addprojects 
  JOIN tasks ON tasks.proj_id = addprojects.id GROUP BY tasks.proj_id ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Laravel uses strict mode. You can disable it from ***config/database.php*** you will see in mysql array config

```
'strict' => true,
```

turn it to **false** and your query will work

study more about **Strict SQL Mode** from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)

Comment: It shows "Undefined property: stdClass::$task_weight "

Comment: there is something wrong with the query. why don't you use eloquent, writing raw sql is always time consuming

Comment: [chek this out](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)  might help you if you are not using Eloquent

Comment: Should I use anything in controlluer . Example: use App\Users

Comment: try this:

`DB::table('addprojects')->join('tasks', 'addprojects.id', '=', 'tasks.proj_id')->select('id', 'emp_id', DB::raw('SUM(tasks.task_weight) as total_task_weight'), tasks.flag )->groupBy('tasks.proj_id')->get();`

Comment: It shows "Use of undefined constant tasks - assumed 'tasks' ". thanks in advance

Comment: try the query [builder methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) I'm sure you'll figure it out, you're on the right track 